# django rest cant get session varible in get request

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have the following class for user's payment progress
when the request is `POST`, I am setting amount in the session like this `request.session['amount'] = amount`
and when the request is `GET` i should get the session but session is empety and the if statement `if 'amount' in request.session:` is always false. How can I fix this??

```
class PaidApiView(APIView):
    MMERCHANT_ID = '??????????'  # Required
    ZARINPAL_WEBSERVICE = 'https://www.zarinpal.com/pg/services/WebGate/wsdl'  # Required
    amount = None  # Required
    description = None  # Required
    products = None
    email = 'user@userurl.ir'  # Optional
    mobile = '09123456789'  # Optional
    CallbackURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/store/paid/'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        amount = request.data['amount']
        products = request.data['products']
        productstitle = request.data['productstitle']
        productsTitlestr = ''.join(productstitle)

        self.amount = amount
        self.products = products
        self.description = productsTitlestr

        request.session['amount'] = amount


        client = Client(self.ZARINPAL_WEBSERVICE)
        result = client.service.PaymentRequest(self.MMERCHANT_ID,
                                               self.amount,
                                               self.description,
                                               self.email,
                                               self.mobile,
                                               self.CallbackURL)
        if result.Status == 100:
            return Response('https://www.zarinpal.com/pg/StartPay/' + result.Authority)
        else:
            return Response('Error')

    def get(self, request):

        if 'amount' in request.session:
            self.amount = request.session['amount']

            client = Client(self.ZARINPAL_WEBSERVICE)
            if request.GET.get('Status') == 'OK':
                result = client.service.PaymentVerification(self.MMERCHANT_ID,
                                                            request.GET['Authority'],
                                                            self.amount)
                if result.Status == 100:
                    del request.session['amount']
                    return Response('Transaction success. RefID: ' + str(result.RefID))
                elif result.Status == 101:
                    del request.session['amount']
                    return Response('Transaction submitted : ' + str(result.Status))
                else:
                    del request.session['amount']
                    return Response('Transaction failed. Status: ' + str(result.Status))
            else:
                del request.session['amount']
                return Response('Transaction failed or canceled by user')

        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: The request used in rest-framework is NOT the same as the normal django request, but sessions should be avaialbe as long as you use SessionAuth and not any of the TokenAuths.

Comment: And your code should probably not trust the client for what amount to charge, do that calculation on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

If you have activated the SessionAuthentication class you will have the session variable. But probably you are using TokenAuthentication, so your best option is to save the data in a table and load it on every request.

Comment: i used JSONWebTokenAuthentication